# Ubuntu User Differences

Tags: 16.04, command-line

When i open the terminal and type

> `su XXXXX`

where terminal open in the name of `XXXXX` , it ask for password and switched. Am i not already there in the first place when i opened the terminal? So What is the differences between terminal open in the first place and terminal open after I switch to same as open in first? I do not seems to find any differences here.
When i type `exit` it exits and bring me where i am before. Am i always in same place or different? If i am on same place why switching account happen ?

Comment: Ok , @karel , could be duplicate in the end of ans, but why switch happen from same user to same user. Also if i do not knew about `su , sudo-s`, i am surely going different way.

Comment: Form that link , i did not get why ubuntu switch me to myself ? Help me out

Comment: Ther command `exit` always returns you back to the same user that you logged in with. If this user is not root then you need to use `sudo` to run commands with root privileges.

Comment: sir, @karel , `exit` does that ,but who am i before switching and after switching myself ? Is there privilege differences , Although why it is switching to myself?

Comment: In order to not be confused by the different variations of `sudo` and `su` you must understand that each one of these variations was created for a different purpose and misusing them can make a disaster. The safest alternative (not always the most time-saving one) is to preface a command by `sudo` every time you want to run that command with root privileges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72965/discussion-between-parlad-neupane-and-karel).

Comment: I ask simply , why it does take me like i am different in two situations ?